# Реализация редиректа с https на http, для ПО с своим веб сервером

Tags: веб-сервер, администрирование

Имеется:
ПО Luxriot VMS, WS 2019.
Описание проблемы:
ТК вебка сервера Luxriot на http, фотки через http на сайте https не работают, пока не включишь небезопасный контекст, что на мобильном не реализуемо.
Описание решения:
Через какие-либо средства запрос https://ip:port/{REQUEST_URL} отлавливать и в ответ выдавать http://ip:port/{REQUEST_URL}.

Через IIS какие то траблы с обработкой localhost:8080, из-за чего не работают правила.

Comment: Нужно не редиректить, а проксировать. Вы описали стандартный reverse proxy.

Comment: Согласен с @AlexeyTen. Я настраивал по этому хауту: https://serveradmin.ru/nginx-proxy_pass/